Unable to install Ubuntu on vsphere 8
Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 on vsphere 8, screen hangs on "select language"
Hypervisor: VMware ESXi, 8.0.2, 23305546
Model: PowerEdge R6525
Processor Type: AMD EPYC 7763 64-Core Processor
